# Java application in Netbeans is not closing properly on cross button

Tags: java, opencv, javafx, webcam, javacv

Okay, So the case is , i am working on a project(in javafx ,opencv, javacv) ,which includes opening webcam option. And it opens perfectly fine.The problem is that , on closing the whole application, the application doesn't close. It(app) keep running in background.

Look at some of the screenshots below-

this is the open webcam button.

[image]

when i click on it, webcam windows opens, as below

[image]

when i close the whole application then

[image],

look at the red button it is not disabled, i.e., it is currently running in background.
For more clarification i saw it in task manager, then look

[image]

the java application is running in background. When i press the red button in netbeans, then this java program in task manager vanishes, ie closes.

A program must not work in background (until we use Threads) when it is closed.

Here is the code what i am doing.

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class WCam //extends Thread
{

static WCam wc;
String globallocaldateAndtime="";
//@Override
//    public void run() 
//    {
    //super.run(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools |     
Templates.
public String method()
{
    opencv_highgui.CvCapture     
    capture=opencv_highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, 
    opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 150);
    opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, 
    opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 200);

    opencv_core.IplImage grabbedImage=opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture);

    CanvasFrame frame=new CanvasFrame("Webcam");
    frame.setCanvasSize(200, 150);

    while(frame.isVisible() && (grabbedImage=opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture))!=null)
    {
        frame.showImage(grabbedImage);
        //imgviewStudentsPic.setImage(new Image(new FileInputStream(grabbedImage)));

    }


     OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber=new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
        try 
        {
            grabber.start();
            opencv_core.IplImage img=grabber.grab();  
            opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage("cap.jpeg",img);


        } 
        catch (FrameGrabber.Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(WCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    opencv_highgui.cvReleaseCapture(capture);
    grabbedImage.release();



//}

}



    WebcamPanel panel=null;
    public static String doStartWebCam()
    {
        WCam webcam=new WCam();
        wc=webcam;
        webcam.method();


    }



}
```

So, can anyone please tell me that, why it is happening so, and how can i resolve this problem.

Comment: I am going to guess that you are doing the webcam work on the GUI thread.

Comment: Yes , i am working on webcam. I haven't kept the code(method) in thread. But main thread is running. Do u have any idea about solving this problem. I have tried to interrupt the main thread ,but it didn't helped. I have also tried to stop the main thread but the stop() shows itself as deleted(Cut line on the text of stop method) method.